# How to change shadow softness of light?

Tags: light, shadows

The option for softness has changed since blender updated and I don't know where to find it[image]

[image]

The bottom one is the old version and has the softness option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like:

- Light **Size** will influence the softness of the light edges and of the objects shadows.

[image]

- Light **Blend** will influence the softness of the light edges only.

[image]